# Moving user folder in Windows 10 by mounting?

Tags: windows-10, mount

There are a number of questions relating to moving the user folder in Windows (but most are not 10)  -- but my question is proposing a different solution -- one that I don't 100% know how to do.

So I have a small disk (C:) and installed a new one and copied C:\ over to the new disk with Macron Reflect (D:) and created a new partition from the remaining free space (E:). I did a `robocopy d:\users e:\ /mir /xj /copyall` as administrator.

Disk management offers me to mount a partition into a folder. So I am thinking on deleting `D:\Users` and mounting `E:\` there. the only problem I have with this is that once I remove C:\ from the system and boot from the previously-D-now-C drive then, I suspect, the mount will break and so will Windows over not finding any users. How could I fix this? Would safe mode start, for example? Is it possible to specify the mount using the Volume GUID?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to specify the mount using the Volume GUID?

So `mountvol` works but there seems to be a necessary trick which I frankly was unable to find anywhere. Here's what I figured out: `dir \\?\Volume{4a2eeb11-1864-47b8-b5e3-4a7e373d49c6}\dirname` works but `dir \\?\Volume{4a2eeb11-1864-47b8-b5e3-4a7e373d49c6}\` does not. I have tried replacing `\` for the root directory and much to my surprise that worked and so does mountvol:

`mountvol "\\?\Volume{bdb9abf2-09db-4f9c-a52c-abf7034b65f1}\Users" "\\?\Volume{4a2eeb11-1864-47b8-b5e3-4a7e373d49c6}\\"`

Note the double slash at the end. I am not sure whether this is better than a junction created by `mklink` but it's working.

Also note https://stackoverflow.com/a/98069/308851 for deleting the users folder.